# How to add a specific metadata using jquery into a div with an ID

Tags: html, jquery, divi

I am trying to figure out how to write jQuery code to insert meta data in to an element, specifically this: `data-section-name="home"`

I want to insert this in a div with an ID of `home-section` and the output would be like this:

```
<div id="home-section" data-section-name="home">
  (some code here...)
</div>
```

I am using a divi builder in Wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the `data` attribute to appear in the HTML source use `attr()`:

```
$('#home-section').attr('data-section-name', 'home');
```

If the data attribute is going to be read by a jQuery library then you can use the `data()` method instead, which is more performant:

```
$('#home-section').data('section-name', 'home');
```

The caveat in both cases is to ensure that you execute this line of code ***before*** whatever library depends on that `data` attribute being present.

Comment: Thank you, The first code worked perfectly. It was .attr rather .data worked on my end

Comment: No problem, glad to help